How to solve this as in cmd its working but on vs code terminal its not working
C:\react>npx create-react-app GGPTL
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm error path C:\react
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs ENOENT
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-07-06T14_18_00_435Z-debug-0.log
its not getting setup
